# Add URL to FullCalendar in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm trying to add url to Fullcalendar in react ,I need when I click on one event that clic takes me to page details of that clicked event. the  `URL` showns on the browser is correct but nothing appers because the browser is quickly refreshed. If anyone have any idea thanks for help.

```
//here some code

events.push(
            {
                title: '\n owner: '+reservation.user.fullname,
                start: reservation.start_date,
                end: reservation.end_date,
                url: '/reservation/details/' + reservation.id + '/' + reservation.space.category.name,
            },

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
       events: evt,
       timezone: 'UTC',

  });
```

Comment: Are you remembering to cancel the default behavior and using the url in fx a window.location or window.open?

Comment: how can i cancel the default behavior ?

Comment: Read the docs https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick

Comment: thanks for helping , i'm using this function ::::: eventClick: function (event) {
          if (event.url) {
            window.open(event.url);
            console.log('click', event.title);
            return false;
          }
        } ====> but nothing change , the new windows refresh just when the url appears

Answer (score 0):

You should use the React version, don't mix it with jQuery
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react

Comment: Is there a problem with jQuery ?

Comment: you have this problem because you using the jQuery version. you can heck it to work with react, but why the effort when you can just change to react fullcalendar?